# Git - remove Git Repo from Dev site but keep contents

Tags: git, repository

I acquired a dev-site from a client. I want to keep the dev site but remove the connection to the other developers repo. Then I want to connect the dev site to my new git repo. What they managed and what I will manage will be different in the repo but the same site

I have read that I can change the repo URL. Is that the best method?
If this is not the best method can you please share what should be?

If I change the URL what happens to everything that was tied to the other repo?

Yes, this has to be done. The only other thing I can think of doing is delete the entire folder and all content and push and rebuild with my repo.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the existing remote:

```
$ git remote rm $EXISTING_REMOTE
```

and add your own:

```
$ git remote add $NEW_REMOTE_NAME $NEW_REMOTE_URL
```

You could also edit the URL on the existing remote:

```
$ git remote set-url $EXISTING_REMOTE $NEW_REMOTE_URL
```

Although I personally think just deleting the old and adding the new is easier.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I needed to better understand this process. Still learning it.

Comment: what if I do not know the old remote name? or path?

Comment: Running `git remote` will show the names of all the remotes set up for the repo.